# Enumeration cases with same variables

Tags: swift, enums

I have an enumeration in my code but most of the cases need **same variables** to perform operations like following:

```
enum Event {   
    case modeActivated(title: String, name: String, category: String, country: String)   
    case modeDeactivated(title: String, name: String, category: String, country: String)   
    case button1Tapped(title: String, name: String, category: String, country: String)   
    case button2Tapped(title: String, name: String, category: String, country: String) 
}
```

Its all okay for now. But when I need to perform operations with these parameters like following, it causes a lot of code repeat.

```
extension SomeEvent: Event {
var parameters: [String: Any] {
    var parameters: [String: Any] = [:]

        switch self {

        case let .modeActivated(title, name, category, country):
              parameters[ParameterKeys.contentTitle.rawValue] = title
              parameters[ParameterKeys.sourceName.rawValue] = name
              parameters[ParameterKeys.sourceCategory.rawValue] = category
              parameters[ParameterKeys.sourceCountry.rawValue] = country
        case let .modeDeactivated(title, name, category, country):
              parameters[ParameterKeys.contentTitle.rawValue] = title
              parameters[ParameterKeys.sourceName.rawValue] = name
              parameters[ParameterKeys.sourceCategory.rawValue] = category
              parameters[ParameterKeys.sourceCountry.rawValue] = country
        case let .button1Tapped(title, name, category, country):
              parameters[ParameterKeys.contentTitle.rawValue] = title
              parameters[ParameterKeys.sourceName.rawValue] = name
              parameters[ParameterKeys.sourceCategory.rawValue] = category
              parameters[ParameterKeys.sourceCountry.rawValue] = country
        case let .button2Tapped(title, name, category, country):
              parameters[ParameterKeys.contentTitle.rawValue] = title
              parameters[ParameterKeys.sourceName.rawValue] = name
              parameters[ParameterKeys.sourceCategory.rawValue] = category
              parameters[ParameterKeys.sourceCountry.rawValue] = country
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any way to avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine the `enum cases` like,

```
var parameters: [String: Any] {
    var parameters: [String: Any] = [:]

    switch self {
    case let .modeActivated(title,name,category,country),
         let .modeDeactivated(title,name,category,country),
         let .button1Tapped(title,name,category,country),
         let .button2Tapped(title,name,category,country):

        parameters[ParameterKeys.contentTitle.rawValue] = title
        parameters[ParameterKeys.sourceName.rawValue] = name
        parameters[ParameterKeys.sourceCategory.rawValue] = category
        parameters[ParameterKeys.sourceCountry.rawValue] = country
    }

    return parameters
}
```

Also, please clarify what `SomeEvent` is. Because the code you added is not compiling.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a calculated property for your enum, like

```
enum Event {
    case modeActivated(title: String, name: String, category: String, country: String)
    case modeDeactivated(title: String, name: String, category: String, country: String)
    case button1Tapped(title: String, name: String, category: String, country: String)
    case button2Tapped(title: String, name: String, category: String, country: String)

    var title:String {
        switch (self) {
        case .modeActivated(let title, _, _, _),
             .modeDeactivated(let title, _, _, _),
             .button1Tapped(let title, _, _, _),
             .button2Tapped(let title, _, _, _):
                return title
        }
    }

    // and so on for the other values like name, category and country
}
```

and then access them like

```
var e:Event = .modeActivated(title: "hello", name: "name", category: "cat", country: "country")
var parameters: [String: Any] = [:]
parameters[ParameterKeys.contentTitle.rawValue] = e.title
```